# What is the terminology of using full words to describe each letter in a vehicle identification number? reversed acronym/initial?

Tags: terminology

In many police procedural TV shows, when police officer try to told partners (or IT guys) the vehicle identification number (or flight number, driver license number, etc...), they will use full word to describe each letter of the number to make sure the information are clearly and unambiguously delivered, such as when describing `ABM`, they may say **A**lpha **B**eta **M**erry.

So what is the terminology of this? It's something like "reversed acronym/initial", but what it is actually called?

Comment: That’s called using a phonetic alphabet.  In the ICAO phonetic alphabet that ’M’ would be 'Mike’

Comment: @Jim, thanks, my memory may got corrupt. I remembered one character said 'Merry', probably messed up with other memories.

Comment: In a poorly researched TV show - of which there have been more than a few - M could be 'Mary'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be referring to [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet):

> The International Radiotelephony Spelling Alphabet, commonly known as the ICAO phonetic alphabet, and in a variation also known officially as the ITU phonetic alphabet and figure code, sometimes called the NATO phonetic alphabet, is the most widely used radiotelephone spelling alphabet.

[image]